# Django request method always return GET

Tags: python, django

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_request(request):
    return JsonResponse({"method":request.method})
```

Postman POST result

```
{
    "method": "GET"
}
```

I try to detect request method, but no matter what request I used, It always return GET

anyone know where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Post your `urls.py` please. Are you sure that's the correct URL and it doesn't have a trailing slash `/` at the end?

Comment: I faced this problem too. I think this problem come from postman. Some time I try older version of postman and this problem wasn't show up.

Comment: path('request/', views.request.get_request),

Comment: oh so I must have / at end!?

Comment: I try again this scenario in clean django application. Are you run your django whit django default web server ro another web server?

Comment: i add / at end, and it works, but cant it accept both? cuz many user dont add /

Comment: I use django channel for my application and I think since I use ASGI/Channel I have faced this problem but with default django server request looks good

Comment: it don't matter much on user side since `last` and `last/` in django basically point to the same route. `last/` will redirect the url to `last`. Slash at the end only important when you calling the api

Comment: ok tyvm for help!

Comment: also django have option to add a slash at the end of url if the url missing it , you can use `APPEND_SLASH` as true or flase in your django setting so if they missing `/` at the end then django will auto add it  then you don't have to worry about when user missing `/`. You can also read django [core design philosophies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/misc/design-philosophies/#url-design) to prefer what you want

Comment: @BenjaminW The problem is, Django is sending a redirect from `/request` to `/request/` breaking the `POST` request (as `301` and `302` redirects must be `GET`). You must change your `path` to fix this issue.